# python function for valley with ascending descending

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, windows-xp

A list of integers is said to be a valley if it consists of a sequence of strictly decreasing values followed by a sequence of strictly increasing values. The decreasing and increasing sequences must be of length at least 2. The last value of the decreasing sequence is the first value of the increasing sequence.

Comment: And what exactly do you want? Is this a homework?

Answer (score 0):

```
def valley(list):
  if(len(list)==0):
    return(True)
  if(len(list)==1):
    return(False)
  if(list[0]<list[1]):
    return(False)
  for i in range(0,len(list)-1):
    if(list[i]<list[i+1]):
      pos=i
      break
    if(list[i]==list[i+1]):
      return(False) 
  else:
    return(False)
  for i in range(pos,len(list)-1):
    if(list[i]>=list[i+1]):
      return(False)
  return(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def valley(l):
if len(l) < 4:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(0,l.index(min(l))):
        if l[i] > l[i+1]:
            i+=1
        else: return False

    for j in range(l.index(min(l)),len(l)-1):
        if l[j] < l[j+1]:
            j+=1
        else: return False

    if i==l.index(min(l)) and j==len(l)-1:
        return True
    else: return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def valley(list):
if (len(list) < 3):
    return False
ucount = 1
lcount = 1
for i in range(0, len(list) - 1):
    if list[i] > list[i + 1]:
        if lcount > 1:
            return False
        ucount = ucount + 1
    if list[i] < list[i + 1]:
        lcount = lcount + 1
    if list[i] == list[i + 1]:
        return False
if ucount >1 and lcount > 1:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Well this code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better answer would incorporate some of the answers above to give a very lean code as shown below.

```
def valley(l):
  if(len(l)<3):
    return(False)
  for i in range(0,len(l)-1):
    if(l[i]<l[i+1]):
      for i in range(i,len(l)-1):
        if(l[i]>=l[i+1]):
          return(False)
      return(True)
    elif(l[i]==l[i+1]):
      return(False) 
    else:
      return(False)
```